# Flutter: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

Tags: flutter, android-studio, riverpod

After adding Riverpod in my flutter and want to run with android studio i got this error:

```
lib/main.dart:3:8: Error: Error when reading '/C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_riverpod-2.4.9/lib/flutter_riverpod.dart/': The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart/';
       ^

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\flutter\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I use Windows 11 and the day before it worked just fine without any error

I already run these:

- in pubspec.yaml: flutter_riverpod: ^2.4.9
- flutter clean
- flutter upgrade

Answer (score 0):

Try the command:

```
flutter pub cache repair
```

If this does not help, then you should try installing the Flutter sdk again.

Also, the problem may be with Windows Defender, which may be blocking something. Although this option is unlikely.